# Generate registration code on Simulated readers on stripe terminal

Tags: stripe-payments, reader

Is it necessary to have a physical reader to generate a new registration code every time we create a new stripe reader, or we can generate using simulated readers, if yes how can we generate the code on test device.

Every time I need to create a reader, I have generated the code from the physical reader device. For testing purpose, I was hoping incase if the physical reader is not available does stripe provide a way to generate the registration code not from physical reader device.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to generate a registration code for a simulated reader, as  there's a designated registration code (`simulated-wpe`). Read [here](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/connect-reader) for more details.